# Using bag of words

Tags: php

I am looking into implementing bag of words approach when dealing with emails stored as text files. I want to use keywords that could indicate that the email needs reply, analyse the emails with binary (something like 1|0|1|0|0 etc depending if the word is used) and then obtain a feature vectors that I could use with different ML algorithms.

I was thinking about using PHP to obtain the feature vectors but I can't find any existing implementations. Is it even possible to do something like that in PHP?

Comment: Is it even possible to do something like that in PHP? Yes!

Comment: What is your question? Just `Is it even possible to do something like that in PHP?` ?

Comment: I looked up online and it seems that all implementations are either in Java or Python, haven't found a single one in PHP so I am wondering whether trying to implement one in PHP is not pointless.

Comment: Are you talking about a classifier? A "bag of words" doesn't make much useful stuff on its own ^^

Comment: Yeah I am talking about classifier, probably didn't explain it well enough. I think I might just try to create an array with the words and then make the code loop through each word and echo 0 for when the word isn't there and 1 when the word is. This might do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

Yes bag of words makes much sense for making classifiers. i am also doing thesis on text classification and i m using php and mysql for it. i m little bit confused about creating bag of words. But after some time it can be done.